# killing a thread dilemma

Tags: python, multithreading

I found two ways to implement my `TerminatableThread` class.
I would like to ask for your pros and cons or opinion for each one of them, is there any difference?

First solution: using the `__stop()` private method of `Thread` class:

```
class TerminatableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **argv):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **argv)

    def terminate(self):
        threading.Thread._Thread__stop(self) #@UndefinedVariable

    @property
    def should_run(self):
        return threading.Thread.is_alive(self)
```

Second solution: using an additional `Event`:

```
class TerminatableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **argv):
        self.__terminated = threading.Event()
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **argv)

    def terminate(self):
        self.__terminated.set()

    @property
    def should_run(self):
        return not self.__terminated.is_set()
```

What do you think?
Thanks

Comment: i think you should not mistreat threads. they have a bad enough lives as it is

Comment: There is only one good approach to thread termination - unless you are an OS and terminating a entire process, you should not attempt it except in the case of direst need.

Answer (score 0):

To the first solution: You shouldn't use a private method, because that can change and is bad form anyway.  Also, a thread shouldn't be stopped cold; you should give the process inside that thread a chance to clean up first, and respond to termination requests on its own.

To the second solution: Abstract classes are less common and less necessary on Python than on some other languages like Java.  If your `TerminatableThread` is itself an abstract class for thread operations, why not add the `terminated` behaviour to it directly?

```
class TerminatableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **argv):
        super.__init__(self, *args, **argv)
        self.terminated = False

    # Note: not actually thread-safe
    def terminate(self):
        self.terminated = True
```

**Edit:** You removed the 'abstract class' proposal, but I would use some kind of thread-safe flag mechanism. Threading Events sound like they might do that, so I would go with that option.

Comment: Thanks. That is interesting. I think I give the right thread-safe way with the `Event` object. I understand that threads shouldn't be terminated synthetically, but have you thought about why this __stop method exists? you can't use it in any other way.

Comment: Most threading mechanisms provide SOME low-level way to terminate them.  But __stop is a private method, and appears to be undocumented, so it may not be present on all platforms. It could just be used internally to stop OS threads when your worker threads complete.  See also: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#thread-objects

Answer (score 0):

Python threads can also be closed with sys.exit() which from within a thread is the same as thread.exit()

```
def nuke(self):
    # set autodestruct, remove thread from stack and exit thread
    global threads
    try:
        threads.remove([self.threadId,self])
    except:
        sys.exit()
```